# Obtener valor de option selected en un elemento child (jquery/javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

tengo el siguiente escenario:

una serie de elementos SELECT en una serie de DIV con igual clase.

```
<div class="elementLine">
persona 1
  <select id="coches">
    <option value='si' selected>si</option>
    <option value='no'>no</option>
  </select>
  <select id="motos">
    <option value='si'>si</option>
    <option value='no' selected>no</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="elementLine">
persona 2...
```

necesito acceder al valor de cada OPTION:SELECTED, iterando por cada linea de la con la funcion .each; el problema es que no puedo obtener el valor del SELECT. ¿alguien sabe como acceder a ese elemento en particular?

```
$( ".elementLine" ).each(function(index, value){ 
    var tieneCoche= $(this).children( $("#coches").children("option:selected") ).val()  ;  
    console.log( "coche value:"+tieneCoche);
});
```

Comment: Si ocupas el valor que se muestra, en lugar de val(), usa text().

Comment: he probado todo tipo de selectores Con val() y con text() y no soy capaz de encontrar el adecuado:
 `var tieneCoche= $(this).find("#coches").filter("option:selected").text() ;`
 `var tieneCoche= $(this).find("#coches option:selected").text() ;` y nada...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es mucho más sencillo de lo que crees, deberías tomar cada `select` en un `each()` para luego obtener el valor de dicho `select` con la función [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) de jQuery.

```js
// cuando esté listo el DOM
$(document).ready(function() {
  // selecciono los select y los recorro en un each
  $('.elementLine select').each(function(index) {
    // obtengo el valor del select
    var value = $(this).val();
    
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elementLine">
persona 1
  <select id="coches">
    <option value='si' selected>si</option>
    <option value='no'>no</option>
  </select>
  <select id="motos">
    <option value='si'>si</option>
    <option value='no' selected>no</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: De acuerdo! funciona correctamente, sin embargo me devuelve el valor de todos los select... ¿hay alguna forma de obtener los elementos por separado? es decir... ¿se puede obtener solo el valor del select 'coches'? por ejemplo.. Muchas gracias

Comment: Si, cambiando el selector, por ejemplo `$('.elementLine select#coches').val()`.

Comment: Bueno, he probado cambiando el selector y efectivamente obtiene el valor del elemento elegido, sin embargo, creo que ha perdido la iteraccion que realizaba por todos los div 'elementLine'... ¿puede ser?no se si es solo mi caso.. Muchas gracias

Comment: lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma: 
`$( ".elementLine" ).each(function(index){ 
var coche= $(this).find('select#coche').val();
console.log("coche:" +coche);
}`
  Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Kleith. Ha sido clave para solucionarlo!

Comment: Claro, si deseabas mantener el ciclo, esa manera era la correcta de realizarlo.